# Find arc length of curve on the given interval

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I was asked to find the arc length of the curve of the following curve:

$24xy = x^4 + 48$ from $x = 2$ to $x = 4$

This has turned out to be a very difficult problem, I get stuck using the arc length formula with the derivative I have calculated.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{x^4}{64}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{4}{x^4}=(\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{2}{x^2})^2$

Answer (score 2):

Why is this difficult for you? Follow the right formula and try to find:

$$\sqrt{1+y'^2}=\frac{(x^4+16)}{8x^2},~~(x\neq 0)$$

Answer (score 1):

We can put
$$\begin{cases} x&=t \\y&=\frac{1}{24}t^3+2t^{-1}\end{cases}$$
Arc length formula $$s=\int_{2}^{4}{\sqrt{(x')^2+(y')^2}\text{d}t}$$ give us 
\begin{align*}
s&=\int_{2}^{4}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{8}t^2-2t^{-2}\right)^2}\text{d}t}\\
 &=\int_{2}^{4}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{8}t^2+2t^{-2}\right)^2}\text{d}t}\\
 &=\int_{2}^{4}{\left(\frac{1}{8}t^2+2t^{-2}\right)\text{d}t}\\
 &=\left[\frac{1}{24}t^3-2t^{-1}\right]_2^4\\
 &=\frac{17}{6}
\end{align*}